# connectedness in discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology

If I have a metric space (x,d) with a discrete metric, are there connected subsets?
To be a connected set, the set itself and the empty set are the only clopen sets.
But every subset of X would be clopen, so are the connected subsets just all the singletons?

If I had a subset of two elements, it would be a set of two disjoint open sets, for example S={(1),(1,000001)}
is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If every subset is open, then for any set $S$ with more than one element, the two sets $\{v\}$ and $S\setminus \{v\}$ are disjoint open subsets whose union is $S$, so $S$ is not connected. But as you say, you cannot do that with a singleton subset, so a singleton is connected.